# BroadcastReceiver onReceive event doesn't fire

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to listen for received SMS messages, but onReceive method is never called.
The program is built for 1.6 version of android, and it runs without errors with 2.3.7 version, but the event I said before doesn't fire.

Any tip?

```
// SMSListener CODE

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    protected String smsBody = "";
    public static final String SMS_EXTRA_NAME = "pdus";
    protected SQLEventDataSource events;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get SMS map from Intent
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Toast.makeText( context, "O evento onReceive foi lançado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        String messages = "";

        if ( extras != null )
        {
            // Get received SMS array
            Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get( SMS_EXTRA_NAME );

            for ( int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i )
            {
                SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[i]);

                String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();

                // check if it's a configuration message
                if (body.substring(0, 5) == "SMED@") {
                    String[] configs = body.split("@"); 
                    events.addEventConfiguration(configs[1], configs[2], configs[3]);
                }

            }

            // Display SMS message
            Toast.makeText( context, messages, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    }
    private void setSmsBody(String smsBody) {
        this.smsBody = smsBody;
    }

    public String getSMSBody() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.smsBody;
    }
}
```

// AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pt.ipbeja.estig.smed"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SMEDGPSActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".SMSListener" android:exported="true" > 
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you literally pasted your manifest, it contains a typo in the required permissions. It currently incorrectly lists the action filter string (android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED) as opposed to the actual permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
```